# jquery - click functionality - small problem

Tags: jquery, click, bind

I have a short question, please :)

I have a script where i make 5 images visible.
The user controls the order in which he clicks the images.

So what I'm trying to accomplish:
If the last image is clicked, there should be a div displayed.

How does jQuery knows if the 5th image is clicked?

The rest (fade-in the div) i figured out already.

Could you please be so kind and give me a little hint on that? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make your click handler add a class when an image is clicked.

```
$(this).addClass("hasBeenClicked");
```

then you can then check the number of clicked images thus

```
if ($("img.hasBeenClicked").length === 5) { alert("All 5 have been clicked"); }
```

To break it down,

```
img.hasBeenClicked
```

is CSS selector syntax for "all the `<IMG>` elements that have the `hasBeenClicked` class".  You can test this out by adding the CSS `<style>img.hasBeenClicked { border: 4px solid red }</style>` to your HTML and seeing what gets a fat red border.

```
$("img.hasBeenClicked")
```

then just invokes the jQuery query operator, `$`, to fetch an array of the `<IMG>` elements that have that class.

```
$("img.hasBeenClicked").length
```

uses the array `.length` property to get the number of `<IMG>` elements with that class.

```
$(this).addClass("hasBeenClicked");
```

is just book-keeping that puts the `hasBeenClicked` class on images when they're clicked.  It won't overcount, since no matter how many times a single image is clicked, it only counts once in the array of nodes returned by `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `$('.myImages').is(":visible")` to test all of the images.

Here's the [jquery docs for .is()](http://api.jquery.com/is).

It might look **something** like this (not exactly, I think):

```
var allVisible = true;

$.each($('.myImages'), function(index, value){
    if( $(value).is(":visible") && allVisible )
    {
        //that's nifty, move on
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        allVisible = false;
    }
});

if( allVisible )
{
    $('#myDiv').show();
}
```

Comment: `:visible` is not valid javascript since `:` is not a prefix operator.  Might you have forgotten some quotes?

Answer (score 0):

Say one of your divs is declared like this:

```
<div id="div5">
<!-- img tag -->
</div>
```

Then you can say `$('#div5').click(function(){ $('#div5').show(); });`

Comment: This only tests that the last one was clicked. The OP needs to know when ALL 5 have been clicked, regardless of order.

Comment: @rocketrest Ah. It seems that I misunderstood what 'last image' meant. Thank you for pointing that out.